# ASP Gridview - Column that either displays button or text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that works like a timetable. There are 3 Columns in the gridview.

Columns are as below

1. From
2. Till
3. Reservate

I want to have a button on the reservate column as long as the spot is free. If the spot is taken I want to display some text instead. 
Currently I am using below markup

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kranbeladung - Crane loading">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="rBtn" runat="server" Text="Reservate" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Any idea how I can achieve that? 
Thanks

Comment: How do you know if the spot is free/taken?

Comment: What flag is in your database to indicate if a spot is open or not?

Comment: i have a column where the id of the user is stored if the spot is taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a trigger, you would have a method that would test the column.  Then populate according to the result.  Below is what you would have in your Grid.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="...">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# CheckAvailability(Eval("Column")) %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you would do the following in code behind:

```
protected Control CheckAvailability(object flag)
{
     if(flag != null)
     {
          // Create a button, then return it.
     }

     else 
     {
          // Create a label, say space available and return.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Greg answer is great but I had to do some changes. With his code I got this in my page:

```
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
```

instead of the Control itself.

In order to work I returned the HTML of the Cotrol, like that:

```
    protected string CheckAvailability(object obj)
    {
        //some logic
        return "<asp:Button runat='server'>ButtonText</asp:Button>";
    }
```